# Need a SelectListItem, not IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, linq

So with this:

```
var eventDates = Context.Waves.Where(w => w.EventId == vipCode.EventId)
    .ToList()
    .Select(w => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = w.StartDateTime.ToString("D"),
            Value = w.WaveId.ToString()
        });
```

It seems that `eventDates` is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.  How do I get it to be an actual `SelectListItem`?

If I change:

```
 var eventDates =
```

To:

```
SelectListItem eventDates =
```

I get this:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'.

**EDIT:**

Seems I need more clarity.  Fair enough!
[image]

I am trying to get these three dates into a dropdown list.

Comment: what you mean by that ?

Comment: What you want to select? Is that enumerable contains only one element?

Comment: see edit to OP.

Comment: why you want it as `SelectListitem` ? there are multiple items of type `SelectListItem` right now

Comment: Your edit does not give any information, do you expect only one result?

Comment: I think you should use First() or FirstOrDefault().

Comment: Of course Select returns an IEnumerable. The result of Select are all the items that match the select critera -- hence why the result type is an IEnumerable (as the result can be anything from zero to many "selected" items)...

Comment: If you have multiple `Waves` that have the same `EventId`, you will select multiple `SelectListItem`s - why do you think there's only one?

Comment: If you are trying to get three dates into a dropdown list, don't you _want_ a collection of `SelectListItem`s?

Comment: ok.  You are right.  I'm a dork.  I want a List<SelectListItem>

Comment: Nope. You want a `SelectList`, with its items being the items you are currently fetching.

Answer (score -1):

What you have right now is correct for your needs - multiple **items** in a single [`SelectList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx).

What you are missing is that you needs to new up a `SelectList` with its `Items` property matching your `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Comment: would you mind deleting your answer so I can delete this question?

Comment: Yes, I would mind. Hopefully this answer would help others in your position (which is what Stack Overflow is all about).